# How to export a database using Fluent NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, export, fluent

How can I export an entire database, with all its tables and data, into a importable file using Fluent NHibernate (or any other preferrable tool)?

Edit: To clarify; the exporting should be made programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think this is a job for you and your particular DBMS.  This isn't really an area that NHibernate is intended for as far as I know. If you need to do it programatically, then I would think scripting would be the way to go.  What DBMS are you using?

Update:

In that case, look at [tsql scripts such as this one](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1070), or [maintenance plans](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/articles/dba/Overview_of_Maintenance_Plans_in_SQL_Server_2008_p1.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Although I haven't tried this, it should/could work. There are numerous articles on the web about exporting a Gridview to Excel. Create and bind the Gridview to your NHibernate objects in the code-behind file. As I said there are loads of articles/examples on the web on how to export from the Gridview.